# string regex replace in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, string, replace

I'm having the below string in my node js.

```
var textToReplace = "Your <b class =\"b_1\">1</b> payment due is $4000.Your 
<b class =\"b_1\">2</b> payment due is $3500. Your <b class =\"b_1\">3</b> 
payment due is $5000.";
```

Here I want to replace `<b class =\"b_1\">*</b>` with `''`. The output is `Your 1 payment due is $4000.Your 2 payment due is $3500. Your 3 payment due is $5000.`.

If this is a normal replace I wouldn't have had any problem, but here I think the best way to replace is by using Regex. This is where I'm confused. In java we have a `stringVariableName.replaceAll()` method. please let me know how can I do this.

Thanks

Comment: `var newString = textToReplace.replace(/<b.*?\/b>\s*/g, '');`. Regex101 [**example**](https://regex101.com/r/zRrAKU/1). Read about the **global modifier** and the **non-greedy regexps**.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir, Thanks for the quick reply. my bad, I actually forgot the actual replaced string, can you please look into my updated question.

Comment: `var newString = textToReplace.replace(/<b.*?>(.*?)<\/b>/g, '$1');`. Regex101 [**example**](https://regex101.com/r/oQYMHg/1).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var newString = textToReplace.replace(/<b.*?>(.*?)<\/b>/g, '$1');
```

---

**Explanation**:

```
<b.*?> : matches the <b ...> opening tag (using the non-greedy quantifier to match as few as possible)
(.*?)  : matches the content of the <b></b> tag (should be grouped so it will be used as a replacement text), it uses the non-greedy quantifier too.
<\/b>  : matches the closing tag
g      : global modifier to match as many as possible
```

then we replace the whole match with the first captured group `$1` which represents the content of the `<b></b>` tag.

---

**Example:**

```js
var str = "Your <b class =\"b_1\">1</b> payment due is $4000.Your <b class =\"b_1\">2</b> payment due is $3500. Your <b class =\"b_1\">3</b> payment due is $5000.";

var newString = str.replace(/<b.*?>(.*?)<\/b>/g, "$1");

console.log(newString);
```

---

[**Regex101 example**](https://regex101.com/r/oQYMHg/1).

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need a RegEx for this but using jQuery you can easily remove the children and return the HTML using a classic one-liner:

```
textReplaced = $('<div>').html(textToReplace).children().remove().end().html();
```

A working fiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/7cgb51ju/

Comment: ehem ehem. He said nodeJS.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this :

```
textToReplace.replace(/<b class =\"b_1\">[0-9]+<\/b>/g, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use **[Regex capturing groups](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups)** with the following **[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/rI6X3T/1)** `/<b.*?>(.*?)<\/b>/g`, you can then use it in your code like this:

```js
var textToReplace = "Your <b class =\"b_1\">1</b> payment due is $4000.Your <b class =\"b_1\">2</b> payment due is $3500. Your <b class =\"b_1\">3</b> payment due is $5000.";


console.log(textToReplace.replace(/<b.*?>(.*?)<\/b>/g, '$1'));
```

And here `'$1'` will preserve the first captured group for `(.*?)`.